# .htaccess - any rewrite rules with variables only working on localhost but not webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

On localhost (xampp) as well as on one webserver everything in my .htaccess file works perfectly fine. However, on the webserver of my client any rewrite rules that include variables do not work. E.g.:

NOT WORKING:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\+]*)$ $1.php?id=$2&siteurl=$3 [L,QSA]
```

WORKING:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(start|home|index)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Anybody any idea why? Is something wrong with the rewrite condition or may it be a webserver issue? Any advice very much appreciated!

Comment: Is support for .htaccess style rules enabled in that system at all? Might be the rewriting module not being present, but more likely it is connected to the value of the `AllowOverride` setting configured on that server.

Comment: Maybe the URL structures are different or the options settings. You may try adding this `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` on top of the rule-set.

Comment: @arkascha yes, now you mention it: the `AllowOverride` is not available with this provider. However, mod_rewrite in general yes. Can this be the problem? Unfortunately I have a very hard time to find out details about the webserver...

Comment: Well, if the rewriting module is present then the `AllowOverride` directive is defined. It is only usable inside the main server configuration however, you might not be able to modify it yourself. In that case you have to ask for it.

Comment: @faa: unfortunately, this gives me this error: `The script could not be executed correctly. Please refer to your error log for details about this error.` - on localhost it works, though..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where this is hosted, but perhaps mod_rewrite isn't enabled?

Comment: thx, David - mod_rewrite is enabled. That's also why I posted the WORKING example. It's hosted on hosteurope, WebPack 4 M, saying mod_rewrite to be enabled.